# Stripe Payments with Angular error: 'Property 'sources' does not exist on type 'Customer | DeletedCustomer'

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am trying to follow a stripe/cloud functions implementation tutorial but i am getting an error.

I am trying to attach a payment source to a customer, but i am getting error: 'Property 'sources' does not exist on type 'Customer | DeletedCustomer'

```
export const attachSource = async(uid: string, source: string) => {

const customer = await getOrCreateCustomer(uid);

const existingSource = customer.sources.data.filter(s => s.id === source).pop();

if (existingSource) {
    return existingSource;
} 
else {
    await stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, { source: source });
    // update default
    return await stripe.customers.update(customer.id, { default_source: source });
}
```

}

the customer.sources is what is giving the error.

Here is the getOrCreateCustomer() function:

```
export const getOrCreateCustomer = async (uid: string) => {
     const user = await getUser(uid);
     const customerId = user && user.stripeCustomerId;

     // If missing customerId, create it
     if (!customerId) {
        return createCustomer(uid);
     } else {
        return stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you using Stripe Elements  or Stripe checkout form ?

Comment: I am using elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getOrCreateCustomer` function returns a Promise if the customer ID already exists instead of a Stripe customer object. Likely your `createCustomer` function does the same as you aren't using `await` or using callback functions to get the result asynchronously. You likely want to amend your code to the following:

```
export const getOrCreateCustomer = async (uid: string) => {
     const user = await getUser(uid);
     const customerId = user && user.stripeCustomerId;

     // If missing customerId, create it
     if (!customerId) {
        // createCustomer likely uses stripe.customers.create, so needs to work asynchronously 
        return await createCustomer(uid);
     } else {
        // asynchronously wait for a customer
        return await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that, it did not seem to resolve the error. I am thinking that the 'customer.sources' is an old version of code that needs to be replaced, but i cannot find anything on it.